# Restore object from archived file

Tags: objective-c, ios, nskeyedarchiver

I'm using

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:data toFile:file];
```

to save NSMutableArray to file. That works fine.

The problem comes when I try to get the array back.

```
NSMutableArray *s = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:file];
```

Here I get

```
Incompatible pointer types sending NSString *__strong to parameter of type NSData
```

What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `unarchiveObjectWithData:`, which expects you to pass it the contents of the file.  Try using `unarchiveObjectWithFile:` instead, which expects you to pass it the filename.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData* arrayData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];
NSMutableArray* s = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:arrayData]
```

For production code, you should do some type/null checking before assuming the data is valid.